# How to get item from array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I get the `tester` value when I know the `id` value.

For example, I know the id is `71` so I want to get the `tester` value `'34,21'`.
Many thanks in advance

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( 
        [id] => 74
        [tester] => (55, 34)
    )
    [1] => Array ( 
        [id] => 71
        [tester] => (34, 21)
    )
)
```

Comment: That's a lot of downvotes :/

Comment: @Ben But fair downvotes.

Comment: @Leri Fair downvotes would provide feedback

Comment: `echo current(array_filter($array, function($i) use ($id) { return $i['id'] == $id; }))['tester'];` If you love one-liners. :D

Comment: @Ben Hovel down arrow and read prompted text. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Loop through the array and check the value:

```
$tester = null;

foreach ($array as $subArray) {
    if ($subArray['id'] == 71) {
        $tester = $subArray['tester'];
        break;
    }
}

var_dump($tester); //(34, 21)
```

If you want to get presicely `34,21`, you can replace anything that isn't numbers or commas with nothing:

```
$tester = preg_replace('/[^0-9,]+/', '', $tester);
var_dump($tester); //34,21
```

---

[**Please read "*How does accepting an answer work?*"**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)